# SQL Server combine rows into single column

Tags: sql-server, database, rows

I have the following table:

```
SID AttributeID ValueID
120       1        3
120       2        4
120       1        2
120       2        2
```

And I wan't to combine the rows with the same AttributeID,to have something like this:

```
SID AttributeID ValueID
120       1        3, 2
120       2        4, 2
```

I have tried the STUFF function but I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Query (after update):

```
SELECT AttributeID, 
abc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ValueID as varchar(250)) FROM SubjectDetails 
WHERE SubjectID=120 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM SubjectDetails WHERE SubjectID=120 GROUP BY AttributeID
```

Result:

```
AttributeID abc
1           3,2,4,2
2           3,2,4,2
```

Comment: cast/convert `ValueID` into a text based type (i.e. `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, etc...)

Comment: I think it has to be possible with int too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using the code:

```
SELECT AttributeID, 
abc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + ValueID FROM SubjectDetails FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM SubjectDetails WHERE SubjectID=120 GROUP BY AttributeID
```

You are building a string, so you cannot use an INT in there without casting it, e.g.

```
...+ CAST(ValueID AS NVARCHAR(10))...
```

I have noticed that your code will not give you what you require, you need:

```
SELECT AttributeID, 
STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ValueID as varchar(250)) FROM SubjectDetails AS S
WHERE [SID]=120
AND S.AttributeID = SD.AttributeID FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS abc 
FROM SubjectDetails AS SD
WHERE [SID]=120 
GROUP BY AttributeID
```

I have changed how it is aliased only because the method you use I believe will be deprecated in a future version of MS SQL Server, if you are using MS SQL server that is...

Comment: I cannot replicate the error on MS SQL 2016 after recreating your tables. What database engine and version are you using? Also, spotted an issue with your code, updated my answer to contain the code you will need to get the desired results.

Comment: exactly that was the problem, I just wanted to post my answer! I forgot to make the link between the two selects

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql), there is a data type precedence with SQL Server.
You're looking at this in particular (**removed excess data**)

> 16. int
> 17. ...
>
> ...
>
> 26. ...
> 27. varchar (including varchar(max) )

So we know that an int is higher than a varchar, so SQL Server is going to try and convert `','` to a int. 
It can't so it errors out!

A work-around is to explicitly cast the int column `ValueID` to a varchar first, then you should have no problems:

```
SELECT AttributeID, 
abc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ValueID as varchar(250)) FROM SubjectDetails FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM SubjectDetails WHERE SubjectID=120 GROUP BY AttributeID
```

**note:** I have no clue how long your `ValueID` column is so I just randomly chose `varchar(250)`

---

*update*
The reason you are getting the same results is because for every row in your `SubjectDetails` table, you are getting the `ValueID`s of the row with `SubjectID` 120.
This is because of this line (highlighted with **);

**Less Correct:**

```
SELECT AttributeID, 
abc = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ValueID as varchar(250)) FROM SubjectDetails 
WHERE **SubjectID=120** FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM SubjectDetails WHERE SubjectID=120 GROUP BY AttributeID
```

If you match the rows together like below, it should get the `ValueID`s of the row with matching `ValueID`s and you should get the results you want:

**More Correct:**

```
SELECT outerSD.AttributeID, 
abc = STUFF((   SELECT ',' + CAST(innerSD.ValueID as varchar(250)) 
                FROM SubjectDetails AS innerSD
                WHERE innerSD.SubjectID = outerSD.SubjectID 
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM SubjectDetails AS outerSD 
WHERE outerSD.SubjectID=120 
GROUP BY outerSD.AttributeID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With Cte([SID], AttributeID ,ValueID)
AS
(
SELECT 120,1, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 120,2, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 120,1, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 120,2, 2
)
SELECT DISTINCT [SID],AttributeID, REVERSE(STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ CAST(ValueID  AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM CTE I 
WHERE I.AttributeID =o.AttributeID  FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''))AS ValueID
FROM Cte o
```

---

OutPut

```
SID|AttributeID|ValueID
120  |1 |   3 ,2
120  |2 |   4 ,2
```